# How to use .Foreground?

Tags: c#, expression-blend

I have an silverlight application with the to following lines somewhere in the app:

```
txtMelding.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
```

and

```
txtMelding.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
```

Later I want to have an IF that checks whenever the foreground color is black or gray. How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it:

```
if (((SolidColorBrush)txtMelding.Foreground).Color == Colors.Gray)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (((SolidBrush)txtMelding.Foreground).Color == Colors.Gray)
{
    // the color is gray
}
```

Comment: I don't believe this will compile, as `Brush` doesn't have a `Color` property.

Comment: @Jon, yeah good point. I just don't know the type of `txtMelding` but you are probably right.

Comment: Got an error: The type or namespace name 'SolidBrush' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly refrence?)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to cast the foreground brush to `SolidBrush` - assuming you know it always *will* be a solid brush:

```
SolidBrush brush = (SolidBrush) txtMelding.Foreground;
if (brush.Color == Colors.Gray)
{
    ...
}
```

If you don't know that it'll always be a `SolidBrush`, you can use `as`:

```
SolidBrush brush = txtMelding.Foreground as SolidBrush;
if (brush != null && brush.Color == Colors.Gray)
```

On the other hand, shouldn't the colour be reflecting some aspect of your state? It may well be better (in design terms) to react to *that* than reacting to the UI appearance.

Comment: Got an error: The type or namespace name 'SolidBrush' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly refrence?)

Answer (score 0):

Another and more cleaner way to set and compare `SolidColorBrushes` is to use the buildin [Brushes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brushes.aspx) which lives in `System.Windows.Media`:

```
txtMelding.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
```

and

```
if(txtMelding.Foreground == Brushes.Black)
```

Much better imo ;)